# Moving an Object

Tags: java

I am trying to move an object stored in an array to different coordinates when entered by a user. e.g if user enters 2,3 the object X appears on the console on these coordinates but when he wants to move the same object X to 5,3. How can I iterate through the arrayList to achieve this. This is my code for moving the ship:

```
public void moveShip2(ArrayList<Ships> player2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
    {            
       for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
          {
           ships=board[i][j];

                if(ships==null)
                {
                    System.out.print("-" +i);
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                else
                {
                System.out.print(ships.getID());
                System.out.print("\t");

                }

          }
          System.out.println();
          System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

This is my code for adding the ship:

```
System.out.println("\nPlease Enter x position for your Battleship:");
        System.in.read(byt);
        str = new String(byt);
        row = Integer.parseInt(str.trim()); 
 System.out.println("\nPlease Enter y position for your Battleship:");
        System.in.read(byt);
        str = new String(byt);
        col = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());

        Ships B1 = new Ships();
        B1.setID("B1");
        B1.setType("Battleship");
        B1.setX(row);
        B1.setY(col);
        player1.add(B1);
        board.addShip(row, col, B3);
        board.moveShip2(player2);
```

Comment: mmmmmmmm i don't get what are you meaning by "moving an object"

Comment: @Victor Moving an element in the array from one location to another. For instance if the object M is at coordinates 2 and 3, the user decides to move the same object M to coordinates 6 and 7. Don't know if that was clear enough.

Comment: Yeah... kind of.. what you should show what kind of data structure are you employing for storing and handling the objects.. i think that would directly affects how to perform what are you looking for....

Comment: @Victor I am using an arrayList to store my data.

Comment: `moveShip()` never uses `player2` and prints the board rather than doing anything to move a ship.

Comment: are you trying to perform a swap? I mean.. switch places between object in different places?  Or given Coordinates X,Y how to locate the Object inside the arrayList?

Comment: @Victor Yes I am trying to switch using given coordinates.

Comment: @ChrisK I am trying to use moveShip() to actually move the objects but stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, you have a list of ships.. but those ships are identified by his coordinates (X,Y).

So when you are playing, you will have to fulfill the order of moving a ship from (xo,y0) to (x1,y1) on the map.

How do you archive that? It depends on the internal data structure that you employ to manage the Ships.

I suggest to use any implementation `Map<2DPoint,Ship>`, given the coordinates you can easily locate the ship, you could a HashMap (Somehow overkill.. but it would works), or you could implement your own matrix like `Ship[][]`. After that : moving the ship from one place to another is a simple swap operation over the map.

Looking at you code, i guess that the `board` instance should have the given structure as a internal member, like a private instance field. Let me give a more visual idea :

```
public class Board {

    private Map<2DPoint,Ship> ships;

    public Board () {
       this.ships = new HashMap<> ();
    }
    public addShip (2DPoint where, Ship ship) {
       this.ships.put(where,ship);
    }
    public moveShip (2DPoint from,2DPoint to) {
       Ship shipToMove = this.ships.get(from);
       if (shipToMove == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no ship at " + from);
       }
       this.ships.put(from,null); // empty the previous cell
       this.ships.put(to,shipToMove); // assign to the new cell the ship.
    }
```

}

Hope it helps a little.

I think that you question should be tagged with design, because, if a not getting a wrong idea, you question involves, both algorithm and data structures.